# Universal(Fat) framework with CocoaPods

Tags: cocoapods, ios-universal-framework

CocoaPod will help to create frameworks, if we adopt "use_frameworks!" in the Podfile. These frameworks are located in ${BUILD_STYLE}-${PLATFORM_NAME}
So I have 4 instances of the same framework:

Debug-iphoneos

Release-iphoneos

Debug-iphonesimulator

Release-iphonesimulator

How to build the universal framework with cocoaPods ??

Comment: did you find out how to use universal framework from cocoapods...if yes please share how did you accomplish it.

Comment: I wrote an extensive guide on how to achieve this: https://eladnava.com/publish-a-universal-binary-ios-framework-in-swift-using-cocoapods/